# External Content Type in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, external-content-type

Can we create external content type for SharePoint online environment? If yes then how can we create it using visual studio 2012? Any suggestion or anyone have done something like this?
I have a requirement to create external content type in Sharepoint Online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure, we can create external content type for SharePoint online environment. See the attached image where I can see the option to select external content type name.[image]

Need to find out how this is done in VS 2012. I tried Napa tools but that doesn't have any option to create external content type. Hopefully, SharePoint Designer could help.

As I promised, I looked into this again. Worked out an example with Visual Studio 2012. What I could understand is

> As of now, Visual Studio supports only BCS model with OData (Open
>   Data Protocol) Services in Apps for SharePoint 2013.

[He is a step by step walk-through of how to create “External Content Type” using Visual Studio 2012 and deploy in SharePoint 2013 Online environment](http://mysharepointlearnings.blogspot.in/2013/10/external-content-type-and-sharepoint.html)

Note: SharePoint Online does not support solutions. It supports only apps
[image]

Comment: Thanks Biju. I also noticed the same that there is a option for creating external list. But my requirement is to create a external content type using Visual Studio 2012. But I am not able to find a way for that.

Comment: Now, I don't have access to VS 2012. Will try it out when I get home and update you!

Comment: Thanks Biju, I am really thankful for you help. It really helped me a lot. But I have another question Can we create external content type using sandbox solution and upload the .wsp file to the sharepoint online site(as we were doing in SP10 online). I know that sandbox is depreciated in SP2013 but still it is there in VS2012. So is there a way to create External Content Type using Sandbox solution.

Comment: updated my answer with answer to your question. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Biju. Yes I noticed that we can't create sandbox solution for share point online.